# Should an answer be accepted when the question is marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure what to do in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182707/how-to-use-replaceall-and-ruledelayed-with-an-association) case.

The question is indeed a duplicate. The comments provide proper guidance and the answers are relevant and helpful.

Should an answer be accepted?

Should a vote for deleting the question altogether be cast?

Comment: Yes, accepting an answer is still fine even when your question has been marked a dupe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. If one of the answer's that was given in your post provides a better answer to your specific question because it is more thorough than any of the previous answers or because it supplies details better adapted to your specific situation, by all means accept it.
2. A question with good additional answers should not be deleted because it a duplicate. Being a duplicate is not a bad thing. The idea behind closing questions as duplicates is get all the answers linked together. Ideally the duplicate questions and answers would be merged together into one site page, but in practice that seldom happens.